# Matching multiples

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I need to match the following using preg_match()

```
cats and dogs
catsAndDogs
i like cats and dogs
```

etc, so i simply stripped out the spaces and lowercased it and used that as my pattern in preg_match();

```
'/catsanddogs/i'
```

But now I need to match the following too:

```
cats+and+dogs
cats_and_dogs
cats+and_Dogs
```

So is there quick and easy way to do a string replace multiple times, other than nesting it? I want to end up with the same pattern to match with.

Thanks.

Comment: Uhm, sorry, i quite don't get what you exactly want to grep & accomplish, but in any case, won't preg_replace_callback do the trick?

Comment: @Hannes, I think a combination of your suggestion and updating the regex to something like '/cats(\+|_)?and(\+|_)?dogs/i' will work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this expression `'/cats([+_-])?and([+_-])?dogs/i'`

edit: just saw that you don't want a + after the "and" when you already have a + before the "and". If that's right then you should use this expression:

`'/cats(\+and\+|\+and_|_and_|and)dogs/i'`

Answer (score 2):

I would go with [@ITroubs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3856720/matching-mulitples/3856785#3856785) answer in this situation, however, you can do multiple character/string replacements with [`strtr`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php) as follows:

```
$trans = array(' ' => '','+' => '','-' => '', '_' => '');
$str = 'cats+and_dogs';
echo strtr($str, $trans); // prints: catsanddogs
```

Read the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php) carefully before use.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I don't think you have well defined your matching rules, but [here is my simplified version](http://regexpal.com/?flags=&regex=%28%3F%3Ac|C%29ats%28%3F%3A%5b%2B_%20%5d%5baA%5d|A%29nd%28%3F%3A%5b%2B_%20%5d%5bdD%5d|D%29ogs&input=cats%20and%20dogs%0AcatsAndDogs%0Ai%20like%20cats%20and%20dogs%0Acats%2Band%2Bdogs%0Acats_and_dogs%0Acats%2Band_Dogs%0AcatsAnddogs):

```
(c|C)ats([+_ ][aA]|A)nd([+_ ][dD]|D)ogs
```

Probably you want to be *case insensitive* because you used `/i` in your pattern, but I would like to chip in with another approach.

The main differences - compared to the other answers - are the expression parts for the **word bounding**. I use `[+_ ][aA]|A`, so that the regex will match 'cats and' or 'catsAnd', but not 'catsand'. So the bottomline is, that I would only match [*camel case*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case) text if there is no whitespace in between.